# Prestashop Custom Fields/Uploads Not Showing

Tags: e-commerce, prestashop, custom-fields

I am hoping this should be a quick question to answer. Can't find an equivalent on S/O nor the Prestashop Forums.

In the back end of Presashop you have the option to set a number of file uploads and text fields.

On that page 'define labels' is not editable.

Regardless of what values you assign to 'file uploads' and 'text fields' the front end product page (product.tpl I believe) shows ONE file upload.

Anyone any idea why the fields defined in the back of Prestashop are not reflected in the front-end shop?
Many thanks in advance,

Martin

Comment: Please specify which version of PrestaShop you have.

Comment: 1.5.3 I believe, I did the upgrade from 1.5 last night with no change in the situation.

Comment: To add a further complication, I've created a clean install on another subdomain and these options are available on the clean install but not on the old one. I have even installed the clients theme and that's not causing the problem. I'm currently in the process of doing a full back-up of the database to restore to the clean install to see if that brings the issue to light.